# Após inclusão/exclusão setar ativo meu tab-panel (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde é possível fazer a inclusão de serviços em um `tab-panel` e na outra `tab-panel` é possível salvar outras informação, porém quando salvo o registo na `tab-panel` de serviços, a `view` retorna novamente para a tab principal. Sei que o motivo é devido a classe `active` no link do meu `tab-panel`, porém como devo fazer para setar o ativo após usar o `create::` ou `->delete` do `Laravel 5.3`?

Abaixo um exemplo da minha aplicação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#detalhes">Detalhes da OS</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#servicos">Serviços</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Você pode guardar a informação em um campo `hidden` e todos os clicks trocar o valor nesse campo `hidden`, ao efetuar uma requisição fazer uma comparação qual item é para ficar com aquela classe `active`. Essa tab é do bootstrap?

Comment: Sim, Virgilio, estou utilizando a mesma tab do bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do `form` tenha um campo do tipo `hidden` que é o responsável de armazenar a última `tab` selecionada, nesse exemplo o nome é `tabSelected`,

```
<form action="/tabpost" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="hidden" id="tabSelected" name="tabSelected" value="{{isset($tabSelected)?$tabSelected:'#home'}}" />
    <div id="myTabs">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li role="presentation" class="{{isset($tabSelected)&&$tabSelected==='#home'?'active':!isset($tabSelected)?'active':''}}"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="{{isset($tabSelected)&&$tabSelected==='#profile'?'active':''}}"><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="{{isset($tabSelected)&&$tabSelected==='#messages'?'active':''}}"><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane{{isset($tabSelected)&&$tabSelected==='#home'?' active':!isset($tabSelected)?' active':''}}" id="home">home</div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane{{isset($tabSelected)&&$tabSelected==='#profile'?' active':''}}" id="profile">profile</div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane{{isset($tabSelected)&&$tabSelected==='#messages'?' active':''}}" id="messages">messages</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
<script>
    $('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
        $(this).tab('show');
        $('#tabSelected').val(e.target.hash);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

e no evento click da `tab` (`$('#myTabs a').click(function (e)`), passa o valor da `tab` selecionada para o campo `hidden` **`tabSelected`** (`$('#tabSelected').val(e.target.hash);`).

Dentro da `div` e `ul` dessa `tab` na `class` tem um código que será gerado o valor `active` dando a seleção da última `tab` que foi escolhida (se for a primeira vez, a primeira `tab` é selecionada por ***padrão***), observe atentamento no código `html`.

Até agora só é alterações na parte da `View`, tem um parte de requisição do servidor que é demonstrada nessas duas rotas, a primeira é o carregamento normal, sem salvar nenhuma informação ou pelo menos alguma tipo de requisição, já a outra recebe um requisição e devolve pra `View` a última `tab` selecioanda:

```
Route::get('tab', function()
{
    return view('tab');
});

Route::post('tabpost', function(Request $request)
{
    $data['tabSelected'] = $request->get('tabSelected');
    return view('tab', $data);
});
```

Isso é um exemplo funcional, que elaborei, pode testar e observar o comportamento e fazer as devidas alterações no seu código, qualquer dúvida é só perguntar